# Cognos 8.4. Russian content and prompt

Tags: oracle, cognos-bi

I have problem with Cognos 8.4:
I have Oracle 11g db with russian content, encoding UTF-8.
When I display information from db in Report Studio to List, all work ok. Russian text displays normal.
But when I create Prompt it don't work with russian content;

Example 1: I have in db column with cell "пользователь user", I create Select & Search Prompt: "Packege Item", "Value to use", and "Value to display" is this column. And now, when I try to find cell "пользователь user" and write in search box "user", the cell is found. But when I write "пользователь" result is empty.

Example 2: I create Value Prompt, and if I choose in this prompt value with russian characters my report is empty. If selected value in Prompt don't contains russian character, all work ok.

In Cognos Configuration / Global configuration "ru" exist